# Questions while setting up the combo XBOX360 + TV + Home Theater

Tags: xbox-360

I'm trying to set up a little combo to enhance the quality of the overall play. Did someone succeed at setting up an XBOX360 to play games on a TV and output the audio through a Home Theater?

I thought that if I can connect the XBOX using HDMI to the TV and use the common connectors with the home theater I might be able to do it, but the ports for both connections are way too close, and I can't connect both.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have mine setup through HDMI to the TV then optical to my 5.1 logitech speakers that I use for my PC/Xbox. Optical is the best way to go with sound systems.

Comment: What Emerica said is probably the most common set up, be it Optical, or analog outputted to the receiver.  Either way, you're using the audio out from your TV.  I don't own an XBox, but I have other electronic devices that won't output audio on other connectors if it's outputting audio on the HDMI connector.

Comment: Good points... I'll check the optical option out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the MS Audio out connector if you want hdmi to your tv and audio to a separate receiver.

Amazon has them for fairly [cheap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WIG4LW).

This is the setup I use, and it works just fine.  The only oddity is that if I don't have my tv on hdmi before I turn the xbox on, it boots into analog output mode.  When I switch my tv over the xbox reboots into hdmi mode.  Doesn't really affect anything, but it's weird.

That assumes you are using optical audio connections though.  If you just want stereo, you don't need anything new, just modify your current xbox cable a bit.  [Instructable here](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Xbox360-HDMI-RCA-audio/#step1) but it basically says pry the plastic spacer off the xbox cable, wrap the metal in electrical tape just in case, and both connectors will fit just fine.

Comment: There are sources for the actual cable produced by Microsoft.  The cables made by others are not all created equal.  Having to modify the cable might not be up their technical area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Try to get thinner cables if possible, or if your TV has optical out, or audio out, use those to connect to the home theatre receiver. Monoprice.com has great prices on cables.

Comment: The cable I ordered from Monoprice works with a HDMI cable plugged into it.  Read the reviews before ordering make sure the most recent reviews confirm its the same cable.